# Get the largest, average and smallest value

Tags: c++, c, math, pixel

To simplify my question, I will use the pixel as a template.

---

What is the fastest way I can calculate which value of a pixel is highest, median and lowest?
For example:

```
unsigned char pixel[] = {128, 255, 64};
unsigned char highest, median, lowest;

get_pixel_values_priority(pixel, &highest, &median, &lowest);
printf("Highest %u\nMedian %u\nLowest %u", highest, median, lowest);
```

Should result:

```
Highest 255
Median 128
Lowest 64
```

Comment: WHAT pixel????? How can a single value of a pixel (or anything else for that matter) be "highest, average and smallest"??? This question is very badly phrased, and of very poor quality!!!

Comment: (rgb)24 ? for example.

Comment: Are you using any library to get pixel intensity value?

Comment: Let's say we have 3 numbers. `R5` `G2` and `B15` the highest is `B` the average is `R` and the lowest is `G` and THAT is what I meant.

Comment: "the average is `R`"? "the lowest is `R`"? WHY???

Comment: Could you let me fix it for 2 seconds. All these question marks make me feel like I have to be like from "The Flash"

Comment: Take all the time you need :)

Comment: You´re searching `if` conditions...

Comment: Yes... 8 `if` conditions are a GREAT solution to this problem Thanks.

Comment: In this case, `R` would be the `median`, not the `average`. The `average` would be 7.3.

Comment: You've tagged it C/C++. At least put some short coding example to explain what **on earth** it is that you want.

Comment: @Malina Instead of writing such replies, just writing the conditions would be faster, and they surely have the fastest runtime.

Comment: Is `pixel[]` an array of three pixels, or the RGB values of a single pixel?

Comment: Is it clear now? The question is with bad quality, because I am NOT a native speaker.. it is very hard to figure out a good quality question all by myself. I would appreciate a chance to clarify.. but it seems I don't have such. I won't ask here again.

Comment: @WeatherVane Are you all confusing me on purpose? How could `unsigned char pixel[]` be the rgb values of a single pixel... By the syntax it is all clear that `pixel[0]` is R value, `pixel[1]` is G value and `pixel[2]` is B value.

Comment: @Malina it is not about native speech, but asking a clear question. Many have been asked in broken English yet are absolutely clear about what has been asked.

Comment: I tried to be clear.. I edited the question 8 times already.. and it is clear now. And useful as well, because this is part of image filtering.

Comment: @Malina There's nothing clarified with your edits. `unsigned char highest, median, lowest;` none of these variables is able to hold a pixel. At least you'll need a `unsigned int` to hold a _"(rgb)24 "_ as you mention it.

Comment: there. Now aware what the function is supposed to do?????

Comment: @barakmanos, a pixel, is made up of 32 bits.  Those 32 bits include a bytes for the transparency,  a byte for the red intensity, a byte for the green intensity, and a byte for the blue intensity.  It seems the OP wants to compare the three base colour intensities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you tagged this with C++, I would use `std::vector` objects mixed with the `std::sort()` algorithm for making it easy to find these stats. Here's a simple example.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<float> numbers = { 1, 4, 3, 2 };

    std::sort(numbers.begin(), numbers.end());

    // numbers = { 1, 2, 3, 4 }

    float min = numbers.front();
    float max = numbers.back();

    float median;
    if (numbers.size() % 2) {   // odd number of elements
        median = numbers[numbers.size() / 2];
    }
    else {                      // even number of elements
        median = (numbers[numbers.size() / 2] + numbers[numbers.size() / 2 - 1]) / 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Evey time I tag both C and C++.. people answer in C++ specific questions :D

Comment: @Malina With compilers being so good at optimizing and speed rarely being an issue (especially not here), there's hardly ever a reason to limit yourself to just C. Don't ever make it harder on yourself than you need it to be.

Answer (score 1):

To calculate the `min`, `max`, or `average/median` of N values requires you to inspect each of them. If you don't, then one of the values you don't inspect could be the real `min`/`max`/`average/median`, if only you had inspected it.

Therefore, the fastest way you can do this is `O(N)`, such as with a loop.

```
std::vector<Pixel> pixels = ...
Pixel min = max = pixels[0];
for (auto item: pixels)
{
  if (item < min)
    min = item;
  if (item > max)
    max = item;
  // etc.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well.. here is my solution merged in 3 functions.

```
unsigned char rgb_min(structRGB source)
{
    unsigned char minimum = source.R;

    if (source.G < minimum) { minimum = source.G; }
    if (source.B < minimum) { minimum = source.B; }

    return minimum;
}

unsigned char rgb_max(structRGB source)
{
    unsigned char maximum = source.R;

    if (source.G > maximum) { maximum = source.G; }
    if (source.B > maximum) { maximum = source.B; }

    return maximum;
}

unsigned char rgb_med(structRGB source)
{
    fgiByte median = source.R;

    if (source.G > median && source.G < source.B) { median = source.G; }
    if (source.B > median && source.B < source.R) { median = source.B; }

    return median;
}
```

Comment: very clean and nicely done

Answer (score 0):

For exactly three values to be sorted, your worst-case running time
will include three comparisons. There is no way to avoid that.

Here is an algorithm with at most three comparisons:

```
unsigned char higher;
unsigned char lower;

if (pixel[0] > pixel[1])
{
  higher = pixel[0];
  lower  = pixel[1];
}
else
{
  higher = pixel[1];
  lower  = pixel[0];
}

if (pixel[2] > higher)
{
  highest = pixel[2];
  median  = higher;
  lowest  = lower;
}
else if (pixel[2] > lower)
{
  highest = higher;
  median  = pixel[2];
  lowest  = lower;
}
else
{
  highest = higher;
  median  = lower;
  lowest  = pixel[2];
}
```

If you don't mind writing code equivalent to last 18 lines twice,
you can put a nested if-elseif-else inside each of the code blocks
of the first if-else statement, and avoid storing temporary variables.
It's possible this (and some other modifications) might optimize runtime
slightly, but if you really care about that you should probably benchmark
the function to find out how long it actually takes.